# Move Element Up the Y-axis When Mouse is Over an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

**Objective:**

- Moving a div element up and down the Y-axis relative to the page (top window).

**Issue:**

- This functionality partially breaks when the element is set on top of an iframe. I can still move the element down the Y-axis but cannot move it up the Y-axis *unless if the mouse is positioned outside of the iframe*.

[Please see this JSFiddel Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/263808/).

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Move the `red` box up and down the Y-axis.
2. Remove the iframe and notice the red box can be moved swiftly along the Y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When over the iframe you're no longer in the parent document. If you want this to work you'll need to put a transparent overlay at the same size and position of the iframe, in the parent document.

Comment: Doing this will cover the iframe. And if the opacity is set to 0, the iframe will still be covered. Is there a way to achieve this without rendering the iframe useless?

Comment: You could hider the overlay on click, then set focus to the iframe. This would then put you back where you started. Alternately, if the iframe content is yours, you can then talk to `window.parent` and call your script.

Comment: For future readers: Added my solution to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/263881/) 
 based on @MacFarlane's suggested solution. See `THE WORKAROUND/SOLUTION` and `SOLUTION` sections in the comments.